# Cumulative sum as dependant subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `transactions` which contains sellers and their transactions: sale, waste, and whenever they receive products. The structure is essentially as follows:

```
seller_id    transaction_date    quantity    reason    product    unit_price
---------    ----------------    --------    ------    -------    ----------
1            2018-01-01                10    import          1         100.0
1            2018-01-01                -5    sale            1         100.0
1            2018-01-01                -1    waste           1         100.0
2            2018-01-01                -3    sale            4          95.5
```

I need a daily summary of each seller, including the value of their sales, waste and starting inventory. The problem is, the starting inventory is a cumulative sum of quantities up until the given day (the imports at the given day is also included). I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    t.seller_id,
    t.transaction_date,
    t.SUM(quantity * unit_price) as amount,
    t.reason as reason,
    (
        SELECT SUM(unit_price * quantity) FROM transactions
        WHERE seller_id = t.seller_id
            AND (transaction_date <= t.transaction_date)
            AND (
                transaction_date < t.transaction_date
                OR reason = 'import'
            ) 
    ) as opening_balance
FROM transactions t
GROUP BY 
    t.transaction_date,
    t.seller_id
    t.reason
```

The query works and I get the desired results. However, even after creating indices for both the outer and the subquery, it takes way too much time (about 30 seconds), because the `opening_balance` query is a dependant subquery which is calculated for each row over and over again.

How can i optimize, or rewrite this query?

**Edit:** the subquery had a small bug with a missing WHERE condition, i fixed it, but the essence of the question is the same. I created a fiddle with example data to play around:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ma7MhufseHxEXLfxhCtGbZ/2

Comment: How much time does it take if you remove `opening_balance` subquery?

Comment: @Samir about 100 ms

Comment: You can create a column `opening_balance` in your `transactions` table. Update values one time in the new column. If feasible keep this values updated from your process or application. Otherwise you can create a trigger that will always recalculate the opening balance whenever new entry is inserted or existing one is updated.

Comment: Also, let me know the query time it takes when you keep only `transaction_date` clause and when only `reason` clause is used. Provide both the times.

Comment: @Samir yes, keeping track of the value "manually" works but I'm trying to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Also, removing the reason does not change the query time significantly.

Comment: Using triggers will be best solution to speed up the response. With triggers you won't have to do it manually each time. One time manual update for all rows, then trigger will take care to keep it updated. Tried to provide the best solution I could as per my knowledge, unless our SO Gurus have any alternative solution to it :))

Comment: @nXu - can pls post us the create table and some sample data

Comment: For better directed help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I agree with Bernd. Make an SQL Fiddle and add a few dozen rows, along with the expected output.

Comment: Alright, I'll make a fiddle.

Comment: @BerndBuffe,  I created an example DB fiddle with data.

Comment: @nXu What is your MySQL Server version ? and can you upgrade to the latest version (8+) ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya it's a MySQL 5.7. 8+ is not an option unfortunately, but it might be upgraded to MariaDB 10.3 in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following approach utilizing User-defined variables can be more performant than using the Correlated Subquery. In your case, a `temp` variable was used to account for the calculation logic, which also get outputted. You can ignore that.

You can try the following query (can add more explanation if needed):

**Query**

```
SELECT dt.reason,
       dt.amount,
       @bal := CASE
                 WHEN dt.reason = 'import'
                      AND @sid <> dt.seller_id THEN dt.amount
                 WHEN dt.reason = 'import' THEN @bal + @temp + dt.amount
                 WHEN @sid = 0
                       OR @sid = dt.seller_id THEN @bal
                 ELSE 0
               end                AS opening_balance,
       @temp := CASE
                  WHEN dt.reason <> 'import'
                       AND @sid = dt.seller_id
                       AND @td = dt.transaction_date THEN @temp + dt.amount
                  ELSE 0
                end               AS temp,
       @sid := dt.seller_id       AS seller_id,
       @td := dt.transaction_date AS transaction_date
FROM   (SELECT seller_id,
               transaction_date,
               reason,
               Sum(quantity * unit_price) AS amount
        FROM   transactions
        WHERE  seller_id IS NOT NULL
        GROUP  BY seller_id,
                  transaction_date,
                  reason
        ORDER  BY seller_id,
                  transaction_date,
                  Field(reason, 'import', 'sale', 'waste')) AS dt
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sid := 0,
                          @td := '',
                          @bal := 0,
                          @temp := 0) AS user_vars;
```

**Result** (note that I have ordered by `seller_id` first and then `transaction_date`)

```
| reason | amount | opening_balance | temp  | seller_id | transaction_date |
| ------ | ------ | --------------- | ----- | --------- | ---------------- |
| import | 1250   | 1250            | 0     | 1         | 2018-12-01       |
| sale   | -850   | 1250            | -850  | 1         | 2018-12-01       |
| waste  | -100   | 1250            | -950  | 1         | 2018-12-01       |
| import | 950    | 1250            | 0     | 1         | 2018-12-02       |
| sale   | -650   | 1250            | -650  | 1         | 2018-12-02       |
| waste  | -450   | 1250            | -1100 | 1         | 2018-12-02       |
| import | 2000   | 2000            | 0     | 2         | 2018-12-01       |
| sale   | -1200  | 2000            | -1200 | 2         | 2018-12-01       |
| waste  | -250   | 2000            | -1450 | 2         | 2018-12-01       |
| import | 750    | 1300            | 0     | 2         | 2018-12-02       |
| sale   | -600   | 1300            | -600  | 2         | 2018-12-02       |
| waste  | -450   | 1300            | -1050 | 2         | 2018-12-02       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ma7MhufseHxEXLfxhCtGbZ/3)

Comment: Thank you! This does work perfectly in the Fiddle, but needs some fine tuning to work on my real database. I'll try to understand it and report back.

Comment: @nXu Let me know what fine tuning is needed for your real-data. If you can tell specific cases; I can fine tune it further. Also, the query can be made performant by using appropriate indexes.

Comment: it had some other parameters and such but I was able to modify the query. It works like a charm and is really fast (it uses existing indexes). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

do thing something like this ?

```
SELECT s.* ,@balance:=@balance+(s.quantity*s.unit_price) AS opening_balance FROM (
    SELECT t.* FROM transactions t
    ORDER BY t.seller_id,t.transaction_date,t.reason
) s
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @balance:=0) AS INIT
GROUP BY s.transaction_date, s.seller_id, s.reason;
```

**SAMPLE**

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from transactions;
+----+-----------+------------------+----------+------------+--------+
| id | seller_id | transaction_date | quantity | unit_price | reason |
+----+-----------+------------------+----------+------------+--------+
|  1 |         1 | 2018-01-01       |       10 |        100 | import |
|  2 |         1 | 2018-01-01       |       -5 |        100 | sale   |
|  3 |         1 | 2018-01-01       |       -1 |        100 | waste  |
|  4 |         2 | 2018-01-01       |       -3 |       99.5 | sale   |
+----+-----------+------------------+----------+------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT s.* ,@balance:=@balance+(s.quantity*s.unit_price) AS opening_balance FROM (
    ->     SELECT t.* FROM transactions t
    ->     ORDER BY t.seller_id,t.transaction_date,t.reason
    -> ) s
    -> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @balance:=0) AS INIT
    -> GROUP BY s.transaction_date, s.seller_id, s.reason;
+----+-----------+------------------+----------+------------+--------+-----------------+
| id | seller_id | transaction_date | quantity | unit_price | reason | opening_balance |
+----+-----------+------------------+----------+------------+--------+-----------------+
|  1 |         1 | 2018-01-01       |       10 |        100 | import |            1000 |
|  2 |         1 | 2018-01-01       |       -5 |        100 | sale   |             500 |
|  3 |         1 | 2018-01-01       |       -1 |        100 | waste  |             400 |
|  4 |         2 | 2018-01-01       |       -3 |       99.5 | sale   |           101.5 |
+----+-----------+------------------+----------+------------+--------+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: This does run on MariaDB 10.3, but throws an error on MySQL 5.7: #1055 - Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 's.quantity' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @nXu - This was only a sample. You can change the sql_mode or better you the field in the group condition.

Comment: Changing sql_mode is not an option for me, and I couldn't explicitly list all fields, as s.quantity and s.unit_price are required for calculating the variable value outside the subquery, but the outer query must not be grouped by them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t.seller_id,
    t.transaction_date,
    SUM(quantity) as amount,
    t.reason as reason,
    quantityImport
FROM transaction t
inner join
(
 select sum(ifnull(quantityImport,0)) quantityImport,p.transaction_date,p.seller_id from 
 ( /* subquery get all the date and seller distinct row */
  select transaction_date  ,seller_id ,reason
  from transaction 
  group by seller_id, transaction_date
 )
 as p
 left join 
 (  /* subquery get all the date and seller and the import quantity */
   select sum(quantity) quantityImport,transaction_date  ,seller_id
   from transaction
   where reason='Import'
   group by seller_id, transaction_date
 ) as n
 on
   p.seller_id=n.seller_id
 and
   p.transaction_date>=n.transaction_date
 group by
   p.seller_id,p.transaction_date
) as q
where
  t.seller_id=q.seller_id
and
  t.transaction_date=q.transaction_date
GROUP BY 
    t.transaction_date,
    t.seller_id,
    t.reason;
```